# Dynamicly define the function name and function body with variables in python

Tags: python, dynamic, function

I have below functions

```
def foo_001(para):
    tmp = para + 2
    return tmp

def foo_002(para):
    tmp = para * 2
    return tmp

def foo_003(para):
    tmp = para / 2
    return tmp

def foo_004(para):
    tmp = para - 2
    return tmp
```

those functions only have different in function names while the algorithm line e.g. "tmp = para - 2", besides that, the rest part are all same.

So, may I know if I can doing something like this:

```
def $fooname (para):         # $ is borrowed try to say fooname is a variable
    $alog                    # $algo is also variable
    return tmp

lst = [
      ['tmp = para + 2', "foo_001"],
      ['tmp = para * 2', "foo_002"],
      ['tmp = para / 2', "foo_003"],
      ['tmp = para - 2', "foo_004"],
      ]
```

In runtime, I can use `lst[0][0]` assign to `$algo` and using `lst[0][1]` assign to `$fooname` in somehow and I can invoke the function via the `lst[0][x]` inside of the lst?

---

## More specific for my problem here

#### file foo.py

```
def foo_001(para): tmp = para + 2 return tmp
def foo_002(para): tmp = para * 2 return tmp
def foo_003(para): tmp = para / 2 return tmp
...
def foo_100(para): tmp = #complex algo, return tmp
```

#### main.py

```
from foo import *
fun_name = ["foo_001","foo_002","foo_002" ... "foo_100"]

src = 1
rzt = [] 
for i in fun_name:
    rzt.extent(eval(i)(src))
```

Here are my questions:

1. Can I get the `fun_name` list in runtime? I want to save them in a text file.
2. I found there's a common part in function definition which is `tmp = #algo`. Can I extract them out form those definitions while can I define the functions in runtime? I want something like this:

#### file foo.py

```
def foo_factory(): 
    # in somehow
    return adict      #function_name/function pair 

template = [
["foo_001","tmp = para + 2"],
["foo_002","tmp = para * 2"],
["foo_002","tmp = para * 2"],
...
["foo_100","tmp = #complex algo"]
```

#### main.py

```
from foo import *
dic = foo_factory(template)
fun_name = dic.keys()
src = 1
rzt = [] 
for i in fun_name:
    rzt.extent(eval(i)(src)) 
        #or
    rzt.extent(dic(i)())
```

Comment: This is not a good thing to do. If you explain *why* you want to do it, we might be able to explain what you should do instead.

Answer (score 1):

How are you going to call these functions if you don't know their name at "creating time"?

Wouldn't it be a better approach to hold an array of functions (closures) parametrized as you see fit?

I.e. (not tested, but should work):

```
def make_foo_func(op):
  def func(para):
    tmp = op(para, 2) 
    return tmp
  return func
```

And then:

```
import operator
foo_001 = make_foo_func(operator.add)
foo_oo2 = make_foo_func(operator.mul)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking in terms of string manipulation and named functions where you should think in terms of higher-order unnamed functions. They make this a breeze, without exploiting any dynamicness ;) (In fact, the Haskell equivalent would be considerably shorter and cleaner.)

Example:

```
import operator as op

def algo_factory(f):
    def algo(para):
        return f(para, 2)
    #maybe, for nicer debugging output: algo.__name__ = "..."
    return algo

algorithms = [
    mkAlgo(op.add),
    mkAlgo(op.mul),
    mkAlgo(op.truediv),
    mkAlgo(op.sub),
    #...
]
```

Also, depending on what you are doing, you might want `algorithms` to be a dict.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want to do is save the functions themselves in a list and retrieve the function you want from the list.

```
foo_container = [foo_001,foo_002,foo_003,foo_004]
```

Then from there, the call:

```
foo_container[0](3)
```

would be the same as:

```
foo_001(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tools for manipulating functions at a high level in Python. However, from what you have written I don't understand what you're trying to do, so I can't say how to do it. So here is some rambling about things that you might find useful.

- Don't write boilerplate code. The moment you find yourself writing the same thing that you wrote a couple of lines above, think to yourself: "how can I abstract this away?". Note that the answer might be "don't, it's easiest this way", but it also might be "aha! I can make a function factory!".
- How on earth is making a function called `foo_02` that performs division useful? I mean, clearly you're trying to simplify a more complicated problem (you *are*, right?) but you've removed all of the details that are useful. Think about the overall architecture of your code to work out why you need these functions.
- Use `operator` a lot. It has functions for `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and all that jazz. For instance:

  ```
  import operator as op
  operator.add(1,2) == 1 + 2
  ```
- Use `functools` a lot. In particular, `partial` is your friend here:

  ```
  >>> from functools import partial
  >>> import operator as op
  >>> double = partial(op.mul, 2)
  >>> double(2)
  4
  >>> double(20)
  40
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The typical answer to dynamical creation of functions are [lambda forms](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms):

```
>>> def make_incrementor(n):
...     return lambda x: x + n
...
>>> f = make_incrementor(42)
>>> f(0)
42
>>> f(1)
43
```

Probably you should use function pointers instead of lists with function names as strings. Also classes might be a concept to clean up your code, but your description is to vague to provide a more detailed answere.